# Print request upon new file in folder

Tags: windows, vb.net, printing, batch-file

I've got the following problem:

I need to make something that checks to see whether a file has been added to a specific folder, ifso this file needs to be printed. I heard Windows maybe has something similar built in?

```
*Program constantly checks whether a file has been added*
File has been added 
File gets printed immediately
```

I have found solutions, but you need to pay for them.

*UPDATE*

```
"Code supplied by Vik"
:start
set SECONDS=60
SET FILENAME=*.jpg
IF EXIST %FILENAME% MSPAINT /p %FILENAME%
choice /C a /T %SECONDS% /D a
DEL /Q %FILENAME%
goto :start
"Edits: COPY *.JPG file to a different folder (E.G. ImageHistory)"
"Edits: DELETE local *.JPG file leaving the monitor folder empty"
```

Any tips or help are welcome!

Comment: Since you want a batch file for this, what program should the batch file call to do the printing?  In other words, what type of file are you "watching" for?  Word doc, PDF, Excel, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file will check if the file printme.jpg exists every 60 seconds. If it exists, it will use the built-in MSPAINT program to print it.  Feel free to configure SECONDS and FILENAME to suit your environment.

```
:start
set SECONDS=60
SET FILENAME=printme.jpg
IF EXIST %FILENAME% MSPAINT /p %FILENAME%
choice /C a /T %SECONDS% /D a
goto :start
```

Additional mods you may want to make:

1. If you are using an older version of Windows like XP, you may not have the CHOICE command.  In that case, use ping to simulate sleeping: `PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL`
2. You can add a line to delete the file after it's printed: `DEL /Q %FILENAME%`

**EDIT** (Below): Added multi-file, move and delete capability

```
set SECONDS=20
set FILEFOLDER=C:\dropfolder
set TEMPFOLDER=%FILEFOLDER%\TEMPFOLDER
set FILEWILDCARD=*.jpg

if not exist "%FILEFOLDER%" ECHO %FILEFOLDER% NOT FOUND ... CTRL-C TO EXIT && PAUSE
if not exist "%TEMPFOLDER%" ECHO %TEMPFOLDER% NOT FOUND ... CTRL-C TO EXIT && PAUSE

:start
cd "%FILEFOLDER%"
dir /b "%FILEWILDCARD%" > filelist.txt
for %%A in (filelist.txt) do if not %%~zA==0 goto printfiles
choice /C a /T %SECONDS% /D a
goto :start

:printfiles
echo FILE(s) FOUND!
del /q "%TEMPFOLDER%\%FILEWILDCARD%"
move "%FILEWILDCARD%" "%TEMPFOLDER%"
cd "%TEMPFOLDER%"
for %%A in ("%FILEWILDCARD%") do MSPAINT /p "%%A"
goto :start
```

Comment: If you do not delete the file, at least move or rename it.

Comment: Good point. That reminds me, MSPAINT might lock the file while it's printing which will prevent a MOVE or DELete.  Add another 60 second sleep before the MOVE/DELete to give the printer some time.

Comment: Then I think it would be better to first move the file to a "processing" folder and go on from there…

Comment: to get any kind of filename i can use *.jpg right? Can you also add a move command or duplicate + move command? So it comes in folder "Images", batchfile copies and moves it to "Imagehistory" the image gets printed and deleted from "Images", leaving "Images" empty.

Comment: and it would be used on W7 system

Comment: I edited and added multi-file (*.jpg) capability, as well as move and delete. You can set your Images and Imagehistory folder by modifying the FILEFOLDER and TEMPFOLDER variables (lines 2 and 3).

Comment: Wow thank you Vik! How does the batchfile know which printer to use or does it use the default printer?

Comment: Default printer.  You'd have to set it in control panel, I don't know if that can be set from a batch file.

Comment: No that's perfect then Vik :) I'll try your leet skilz out when I get home ;)

Comment: Works like a charm Vik! A+++++ :)

Answer (score 1):

Run a VB.Net in Background and use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to get events for each change in that folder. Upon receiving an event, check the file / action and print the file using whatever App that can print them. A Batch file will likely not work here.